# Как правильно передать указатель на массив структур в стеке без создания промежуточного указателя?

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, стек

Хочется избавиться от промежуточного указателя coordinate_P, только не могу понять как правильно передать указатель на массив структур coordinate, для которого выделена память в стеке. Компилятор ругается:

> main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:46:20: warning: assignment from
>   incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>   total->coordinate = &coordinate[0];

```
//gcc --std=c11 -g -O0 -DDEBUG -Wall main.c
//cat ./main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

} Coordinate;

typedef struct
{
    Coordinate **coordinate;
} Total;

void count(Total *total)
{
    total->coordinate[0]->X = 1ULL;
    total->coordinate[0]->Y = 2.0;
    total->coordinate[0]->Z = 3.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Инициализация структуры total и создание указателя
    Total total_P; Total *total = &total_P;
    // Заполнение нулями (во избежание);
    memset(total,0x0,sizeof(Total));

    // Инициализация структуры в стеке
    Coordinate coordinate[3];
    // Заполнение нулями (во избежание);
    memset(&coordinate,0x0,sizeof(coordinate));

    // Промежуточных указатель на массив структур
    Coordinate *coordinate_P = coordinate;

    // Указатель на промежуточный указатель
    total->coordinate = &coordinate_P;

    // Хотелось бы обойтись без промежуточного указатея oordinate_P. Как-нибудь так:
    //total->coordinate = &coordinate[0];

    //Передать аргумент (указатель на структуру Total) в функцию
    count(total);

    // Вывод результата
    printf("X=%zu,Y=%.6f,Z=%.6f\n",total->coordinate[0]->X,total->coordinate[0]->Y,total->coordinate[0]->Z);
}
```

Пояснение почему именно так:

1. Массив структур нужен в стеке, не в куче.
2. Нужно везде использовать такой синтаксис для обращения к элементам структуры: total->coordinate[0]->X (а не так, что точка в одном месте, а знак    "->" в другом).

**UPDATE 0:**

Пример, более точно отражающий потребности стиля обращения к данным через "->", но, тут используется куча, а нужно хранить массив структур Coordinate coordinate[3]; в стеке.

```
//gcc --std=c11 -g -O0 -DDEBUG -Wall main.c
//cat ./main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

} Coordinate;

typedef struct
{
    Coordinate **coordinate;
} Total;

void count(Total *total)
{
    total->coordinate[0]->X = 1ULL;

    total->coordinate[1]->Y = 2.0;

    total->coordinate[2]->Z = 3.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Инициализация структуры total и создание указателя
    Total total_P; Total *total = &total_P;
    // Заполнение нулями (во избежание);
    memset(total,0x0,sizeof(Total));

    // Инициализация структуры в куче
    Coordinate *coordinate[3];
    // Заполнение нулями (во избежание);
    memset(&coordinate,0x0,sizeof(coordinate));

    // Выделение памяти в куче
    coordinate[0] = (Coordinate*)calloc((size_t)1,sizeof(Coordinate));
    coordinate[1] = (Coordinate*)calloc((size_t)1,sizeof(Coordinate));
    coordinate[2] = (Coordinate*)calloc((size_t)1,sizeof(Coordinate));

    // Указатель на промежуточный указатель
    total->coordinate = coordinate;

    //Передать аргумент (указатель на структуру Total) в функцию
    count(total);

    // Вывод результата
    printf("X_0=%zu,Y_1=%.6f,Z_2=%.6f\n",total->coordinate[0]->X,total->coordinate[1]->Y,total->coordinate[2]->Z);

    free(coordinate[0]);
    free(coordinate[1]);
    free(coordinate[2]);
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Версия, удовлетворяющая задумке и сформированная по результатам ответов комъюнити:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 3

typedef struct
{
    size_t X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

} Coordinate;

typedef struct
{
    Coordinate **coordinate;
} Total;

void count(Total *total)
{
    total->coordinate[0]->X = 1ULL;

    total->coordinate[1]->Y = 2.0;

    total->coordinate[2]->Z = 3.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Initiate structure "total" and a pointer to it
    Total total_P; Total *total = &total_P;
    // Zeroing
    memset(total,0x0,sizeof(Total));

    // Initiate a pointer to the structure within a stack
    Coordinate *coordinate[SIZE];
    // Zeroing
    memset(&coordinate,0x0,sizeof(coordinate));

    // Initiate an array of structures within a stack
    Coordinate position[SIZE];

    // Zeroing
    memset(&position,0x0,(size_t)SIZE * sizeof(Coordinate));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        coordinate[i] = &(position)[i];
    }

    total->coordinate = coordinate;

    // Call a function
    count(total);

    // Print result
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu: X_0=%zu,Y_1=%.6f,Z_2=%.6f\n",i,total->coordinate[i]->X,total->coordinate[i]->Y,total->coordinate[i]->Z);
    }

}
```

Comment: почему/зачем `Total::coordinate` — это указатель на указатель?

Comment: @Fat-Zer сорян, вопроса не понял по причине приведённого синтаксиса. В чём я не силён, так это в плюсах. От слова "совсем" )

Comment: Пояснение почему так: 1. Массив структур нужен в стеке, не в куче. 2. Нужно везде использовать такой синтаксис: total->coordinate[0]->X (а не точка в одном месте, а "->" в другом для адресации).

Comment: (1) — почему массив, если здесь всего один элемент, иначе не релевантно; по поводу (2) — o_O это чья-то странная обязательная прихоть? если нет, то это абсурдная практика...

Comment: @Fat-Zer В примере действительно используется только один элемент total->coordinate[0]. Очевидно, что это упрощение. Сейчас добавлю ещё, чтобы улучшить читабельность.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Чем именно эта практика абсурднее других? ) Обоснуйте с точки зрения удобства или производительности.

Comment: @Fat-Zer (1) Намёк понял. Где-то я налажал в указателях. При попытке сделать обращение к дргим элементам массива, например otal->coordinate[1]->X получаю сегфол (((( Как сделать правильно?

Comment: зависит от того, что именно «сделать правильно»... пока всё сделано настолько странно, что угадать это сложно... а абсурдна, потому что это два взаимодополняющие друг друга оператора... программировать без одного можно, но синтаксис будет выглядеть куда хуже вроде писать `(&coord)->x` вместо `coord.x`, а подганять структуру данных под синтаксис всё равно что выбирать планировку дома, чтобы конкретный рисунок обоев смотрелся выигрышней..

Comment: @Fat-Zer я сделал UPDATE в своём посте. Надеюсь, это позволит уточнить мой вопрос. Добавлен тот код, который хотелось бы видеть, но увы, он не работает. Что именно не так - за гранью моего понимания (((( Я могу сделать массив структур в куче и будет работать, но проблема как раз в том, чтобы массив структур был в стеке.

Comment: вероятно, ты хотел сделать что-то [такое](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/3N2l88Za7k4N0bKHV3xT/)?…

Comment: или если не менять структуру данных, то что-то [такое](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/27bUCSxpGWQkgUFjTnBV/)...

Comment: Оба варианты понятны и очевидны. Первый вариант поизящнее ) В идеале, хотелось бы однообразие в обращении к данным: total->coordinate[1]->Y Вот [тот же пример, только используется куча](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/9GtyAwkhn1COX41OyJ95/) Там именно такое, однотипное обращение к данным. Будь-то снаружи функции или внутри функции которая вызывается из другой функции. Неужели нельзя обращаться к данным в стеке по тому же принципу? Ведь адресация ничем не отличается, что при обращении к куче, что при обращении к стеку!

Comment: да [пожалуйста](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/NRp2f2HbwuRvRgqxAgDm/), но повторюсь, такая гирлянда ради «симпатичных стрелочек в коде» является абсурдной...

Comment: Это то, что нужно!!! )))) Всё зависит от того, сколько именно кода. У меня пачка структур и в куче и в стеке. Путаница с точками и стрелочками надоела радикально, т.к. такого рода обращений в коде просто тонны. Я лучше сделаю один раз гирлянду, чтобы потом тысячу раз не оступаться о точку ) @Fat-Zer Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, код в виде ответа, чтобы я мог поставить "решено".

Answer (score 1):

Я изменил двойной указатель на указатель на массив. Вроде работает.

```
//gcc --std=c11 -g -O0 -DDEBUG -Wall main.c
//cat ./main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

} Coordinate;

typedef struct
{
    //Coordinate **coordinate;
        Coordinate ( * coordinate ) [3];
} Total;

void count(Total *total)
{
        //total->coordinate[0]->X = 1ULL;
    ((*total->coordinate)[0]).X = 1ULL;

    //total->coordinate[1]->Y = 2.0;
        ((*total->coordinate)[1]).Y = 2.0;

    //total->coordinate[2]->Z = 3.0;
        ((*total->coordinate)[2]).Z = 3.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Инициализация структуры total и создание указателя
    Total total_P; Total *total = &total_P;
    // Заполнение нулями (во избежание);
    memset(total,0x0,sizeof(Total));

    // Инициализация структуры в стеке
    Coordinate coordinate[3];
    // Заполнение нулями (во избежание);
    memset(&coordinate,0x0,sizeof(coordinate));

    // Промежуточных указатель на массив структур
    //Coordinate *coordinate_P = coordinate;

    // Указатель на промежуточный указатель
    //total->coordinate = &coordinate_P;

    // Хотелось бы обойтись без промежуточного указатея oordinate_P. Как-нибудь так:
    //total->coordinate = &coordinate[0];
        total->coordinate = & coordinate ;

    //Передать аргумент (указатель на структуру Total) в функцию
    count(total);

    // Вывод результата
    //printf("X=%zu,Y=%.6f,Z=%.6f\n",total->coordinate[0]->X,total->coordinate[1]->Y,total->coordinate[2]->Z);
        printf("X=%zu,Y=%.6f,Z=%.6f\n",((*total->coordinate)[0]).X,((*total->coordinate)[1]).Y,((*total->coordinate)[2]).Z);
        printf("&((*(total->coordinate))[0].X)=%p\n",&((*(total->coordinate))[0].X));
        printf("&(coordinate[0].X)=%p\n",&(coordinate[0].X));
        printf("&((*(total->coordinate))[1].Y)=%p\n",&((*(total->coordinate))[1].Y));
        printf("&(coordinate[1].Y)=%p\n",&(coordinate[1].Y));
        printf("&((*(total->coordinate))[2].Z)=%p\n",&((*(total->coordinate))[2].Z));
        printf("&(coordinate[2].Z)=%p\n",&(coordinate[2].Z));
}
```

Comment: Видимо, я привёл неудачный пример (((( Мне действительно нужен массив структур и возможность обращаться к каждому элементу в массиве. Например, вот три разных элемента X: total->coordinate[0]->X; total->coordinate[1]->X;total->coordinate[3]->X

Comment: Свежий ответ. А так ?

Comment: У меня в реальном коде много структур и в куче, и в стеке. Я надеялся упростить синтаксис обращения к их элементам, избавившись от точки и приведя код к общему виду через "->".  Действительно спасибо за пример, раздвигающий грани понимания синтаксиса указателей, но я, пожалуй, оставлю обращение через точку ;)

Comment: Тогда берёте адрес : `((*total->coordinate)[2]).Z = 3.0;` => `(&((*(total->coordinate))[2]))->Z = 3.0;` . Так вам красивее ?

Comment: Это феерично! )))